# AWS Cognito User Cannot Invoke Lambda (403 Not Authorized)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I’ve created a set of AWS Lambdas using the Serverless framework, and a React app which calls these. A user pool and an identity pool have been setup in AWS Cognito, and a table in DynamoDB. (I've followed the tutorial on serverless-stack.com). It's a simple notes app.

The client app is deployed to: https://dev.cakebook.co

The API is deployed: https://api.cakebook.co/dev/orders

However, after I log in using this Cognito user:

admin@example.com
Passw0rd!

I get a 403 response for the GET of the orders:

```
message: “User: arn:aws:sts::********8766:assumed-role/cakebook-api-dev-CognitoAuthRole-1DTRT5XGEGRXW/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:********8766:sss6l7svxc/dev/GET/orders”
```

I'm new to all this, but it looks like my Cognito user does not have permission to call the Lambda (or API gateway?). Is that the issue? If so, how do I give the users permission to call the Lambdas?

**UPDATE, requested JSON**

**Execution Role:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:********8766:log-group:/aws/lambda/cakebook-api-dev-create:*",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:********8766:log-group:/aws/lambda/cakebook-api-dev-get:*",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:********8766:log-group:/aws/lambda/cakebook-api-dev-list:*",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:********8766:log-group:/aws/lambda/cakebook-api-dev-update:*",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:********8766:log-group:/aws/lambda/cakebook-api-dev-delete:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:********8766:log-group:/aws/lambda/cakebook-api-dev-create:*:*",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:********8766:log-group:/aws/lambda/cakebook-api-dev-get:*:*",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:********8766:log-group:/aws/lambda/cakebook-api-dev-list:*:*",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:********8766:log-group:/aws/lambda/cakebook-api-dev-update:*:*",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:********8766:log-group:/aws/lambda/cakebook-api-dev-delete:*:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:********8766:table/orders"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:********8766:function:cakebook-api-dev-list",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cognito-identity:us-east-2:********8766:identitypool/us-east-2:d9e4e505-c64a-4836-8e56-3af843dbe453"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Function Policy:**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "cakebook-api-dev-ListLambdaPermissionApiGateway-U7OCBI3JM44G",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:********8766:function:cakebook-api-dev-list",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:********8766:w5o4vxx4f0/*/*"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "lambda-da48f6d0-6d3c-4bbf-a761-ca3510f79624",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cognito-sync.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:********8766:function:cakebook-api-dev-list",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cognito-identity:us-east-2:********8766:identitypool/us-east-2:d9e4e505-c64a-4836-8e56-3af843dbe453"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update Lambda permission to allow invoking by Cognito user pool.

**Option A - update permission in JSON format**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "lambda-something",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cognito-sync.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:__accountId__:__function_name__",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
           "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cognito-identity:eu-west-1:__accountId__:identitypool/eu-west-1:....."
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Option B - in console**

1. Go to Lambda Configuration page
2. Add trigger Cognito Sync Trigger
3. During saving it will offer to configure Lambda permission automatically - agree

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did not know exactly what steps to take for Option A, so I tried Option B. I logged out and in again with the same user but I still get the same issue. Do I need to redeploy my Lambdas after adding the Cognito Sync Trigger, or should it work immediately?

Comment: I've also now tried Option A. Though I may have done it wrong. In IAM roles, I selected the "cakebook-api-dev-us-east-2-lambdaRole" role. I modified the permissions policy JSON, adding the to the array of statements the one you provided and saved. But still, I get the same 403 issue.

Comment: @SeánMcGowan it works immediately, no need to re-deploy the Lambda. Could you add to your post Function Policy and Execution Role for your Lambda? That is 2 json files, you can find them in console on a Lambda configuration page. Then we could look what's wrong with it.

Comment: I went into the Lambda's configuration page. I scrolled down to the Execution Role box. I clicked the link below the Existing Role drop-down to navigate to the IAM console for the role. I copied the JSON from there. But it's only one file. I don't know where to find the "Function Policy" JSON you mentioned.

Comment: @SeánMcGowan no need to scroll down, in the top of the page in "Designer" section there is a square box with "key" sign, if you press it - you'll see Function policy. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-create-function.html

Comment: Ah I found it, thanks. I've updated the question to include the function policy.